# Is it possible to combine multiple category__in arguments in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to produce a query that returns posts which are in one array of categories and also in another array of categories. So, if my two arrays are:

```
$offices = Array ( [0] => 73 [1] => 74 )

$grants = Array ( [0] => 108 [1] => 109 ) )
```

I'd want to include posts that matched either terms 108 or 109 AND matched either terms 73 or 74.

Is this possible? My instinct was to user category__in, but you can only use this once, and if I combined the arrays, it matches posts in any of the categories, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd want to include posts that matched either terms 108 or 109 AND matched either terms 73 or 74.

Taxonomy Parameters will work for Category too as Category is a builtin Taxonomy.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array( 73, 74 ),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array( 108, 109 ),
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

[Codex WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Answer (score -1):

Might this query help you ?

```
$Query = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id)
    WHERE $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
    AND ($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = '".$offices[0]."' OR $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = '".$offices[1]."')
    AND ($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = '".$grants[0]."' OR $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = '".$grants[0]."')
    ORDER BY $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value ASC"

    $post = $wpdb->get_results($Query);
```